# how to avoid inserting duplicates on a key-less table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, merge

I was asked to convert the below code into a **merge**. It used to run once a month, and it should run daily now…

Before the below, **EmailEvent** gets truncated:

```
DECLARE @upperLimit DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @lowerLimit DATETIME = DATEADD(day,-1,@upperLimit);

WHILE @upperLimit > '2013-01-31 10:03:09.000'
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO EmailEvent
 Select l.SalesForceID, 
       DENSE_RANK ( ) OVER (PARTITION BY es.email order by sentdate) as [EmailCount],
       es.SentDate,
       esd.eventtype,
       esd.eventdate

 FROM EmailSentDetails esd
 join Silverpop_EmailSent es on esd.emailsent_id = es.EmailSent_ID
 join Leads l on l.Email = es.Email

 WHERE es.SentDate <= @upperLimit AND es.SentDate >= @lowerLimit 


 SET @upperLimit = @lowerLimit;
 SET @lowerLimit = DATEADD(day,-1, @lowerLimit);

END
```

I know MERGE can’t be done, because there is no key on **EmailEvent** (no way to identify a row uniquely!)

The only thing I can think of is, instead of truncating/inserting, just adding the below, will it improve it? is it a valid way of avoind a truncate/insert?

```
WHERE Not exists (select 1 from EmailEvent ev 
                  where ev.salsforceId=l.SalesForceID 
                  and ev.emailcount = DENSE_RANK ()OVER(PARTITION BY es.email order by sentdate) 
                  and ev.sentDate=es.SentDate 
                  and ev.EventDate=esd.EventDate)
```

Comment: what about adding a primary key?

Comment: Can you not add a key for some reason?

Comment: I'm a bit lost as to why you're even looping rather than a larger insert too.... Looks like you could create a subquery to get your data and then just do a bigger insert, but I may be very wrong here....

Comment: even if I add it, there is not one key at source.

Comment: Why that time in the upper limit?  Why not just by day.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean? it is already by day.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a MERGE on all the columns in the table.

But that would be overkill, since you'd never do any updates with the MERGE.

All you really need to do is an INSERT .. WHERE NOT EXISTS() that checks all the columns in the table, just as you suggested in your question.   That's how I'd do it.

Answer (score 0):

Put a unique index on the column(s) you want to avoid having duplicates and use IGNORE_DUP_KEY. This ignores attempts to add duplicates, allowing inserts to continue:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AvoidDuplicateEntries] ON [dbo].[MyTable]
(
    [MyColumn1] ASC --, [MyColumn2] ASC, [MyColumn3] ASC etc.
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

Comment: uniquness comes from SalesforceId, EmailCount, SentDate, EventType, EventDate, so basically the entire table, shall I add it like that?

Comment: @Chicago1988 It wastes disk space and performance, but perhaps you don't have an option? You can put the columns in any order but add so that queries will find it useful, at least.

Comment: It is actually dumb to create a unique index as it will consume a lot of ressources (CPU/Storage) just to avoid the duplicates , [UNIQUE CONSTRAINT](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/unique.php) exists notably for that reason.

Comment: @ThomasG Are you sure they are different?

Comment: @ThomasG The attempt is to stop inserting duplicates. A unique constraint will stop all insertions if a duplicate is attempted, but my proposal just ignores duplicates. I explained that it is wasteful but it does solve the issue; the uniqueness being across all columns was only just explained.